# Deciphering a Regex

Tags: .net, regex

Please can someone help me understand this regular expression used to match `src` attributes of `img` tags in HTML?

```
src=(?:(['""])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<src>[^\s>]+))


src=                               this is easy
(?:(['""])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)     ?: is unknown (['""]) matches either single or double quotes, followed by a named group "src" that matches unknown strings
\1                                 unknown
|                                  "or"
(?<src>[^\s>]+))                   named group "src" matches one or more of line start or whitespace
```

In brief what does `?:` mean?

So `(?:...)` is a non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Thanks @mbratch

what does \1 mean?

And finally, does the exclamation mark have any special significance here? (negation?)

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: it doesn't matter.parsing html with regex itself is wrong

Comment: Parsing the inside of a single tag with regex is actually probably fine

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/674700)

Comment: (?:...)
is a non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Comment: I am not parsing html with Regexes!

Comment: @Alex that is the most famous post on here. I have seen it. I am aware!

Comment: @murgatroid99 What does the \1 mean?

Comment: `\1` (or in context, `(?!\1)` I think references back to the match for `(['""])`, and in the context means "anything but what was matched previously with `['""]`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example, consider `src="img.jpg"` as the text we are parsing

In a regex, `\1` refers to the first capturing group. In this particular case, the first capturing group is `(['""])`. The section `(?:(['""])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)` is a non-capturing group that matches `"img.jpg` in our example. In particular, `(['""])` matches any quote character. Then `(?!\1)` is a negative lookahead for the quote character matched in the first group, so `(?:(?!\1).)` matches any character that is not the quote character matched by the first group and `(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)` matches, in a named capturing group, a sequence of characters that precedes the end quote character. Then the following `\1` matches the end quote character.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you understand the regex.

```
(?:(['""])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1|([^\s>]+))
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/4yEsgJLbMYOGPk8Q)

Answer (score 2):

```
src=      # matches literal "src="
(?:       # the ?: suppresses capturing. generally a good practice if capturing
          # is not explicitly necessary
  (['"])  # matches either ' or ", and captures what was matched in group 1
          # (because this is the first set of parentheses where capturing is not
          # suppressed)
  (?<src> # start another (named) capturing group with the name "src"
    (?:   # start non-capturing group
      (?!\1)
          # a negative lookahead, if its contents match, the lookahead causes the
          # pattern to fail
          # the \1 is a backreference and matches what was matched in capturing
          # group no. 1
    .)*   # match any character, end of non-capturing group, repeat
          # summary of this non-capturing group: for each character, check that
          # it is not the kind of quote we matched at the start. if it's not,
          # then consume it. repeat as long as possible.

  )       # end of capturing group "src"
  \1      # again a backreference to what was matched inside capturing group 1
          # i.e. match the same kind of quote that started the attribute value
|         # or
  (?<src> # again a capturing group with the name "src"
    [^\s>]+
          # match as many non-space, non-> character as possible (at least one)
  )       # end of capturing group. this case treats unquoted attribute values.
)         # end of non-capturing group (which was used to group the alternation)
```

Some further reading for you:

- [Grouping, Capturing and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

If you want to refresh your regex knowledge a bit, I recommend reading through the entire tutorial. It's definitely worth your time.

A few more resources to get help with understanding complicated expressions:

- [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/eI2bG3) generates an explanation from a regex. However, it uses PHP's PCRE engine, so it will choke on some of the .NET features like repeated named capturing groups (in your case the `src`).
- [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/AWwcMzWA_e3n1Ghg) which lets you step through the regex and generates a flowchart. So far it's regex flavor is even more limited though (to JavaScript's ECMAScript flavour)
- [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) which focuses on the flowchart tihng. As of now it's also limited to JavaScript regex flavor, though.

Answer (score 1):

1>It first captures any 1 of `['""]` in group 1 i.e `(['""])`

2>Then it matches 0 to many character which is not the one captured in group 1 i.e `(?:(?!\1).)*`

3>It does step 2 till it matches the one captured in group 1 i.e `\1`

The above 3 steps is similar to `(['""])[^\1]*\1`

**OR**

1>it matches all the non space,> characters after `src=` i.e `[^\s>]+`

---

**NOTE**
I would use `src=(['""]).*?\1`

`.*` is greedy,it matches as much as it can..

`.*?` is lazy,it matches as less as it can..

For example,consider this string `hello hi world`

for regex `^h.*l` output would be `hello hi worl`

for regex `^h.*?l` output would be `hel`

Comment: Please can you explain the `*?` part of your suggested regex?

Answer (score 1):

I used RegexBuddy to get this output:

```
Match the characters “src=” literally «src=»
Match the regular expression below «(?:(['""])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<src>[^\s>]+))»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(['""])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(['""])»
         Match a single character present in the list “'"” «['""]»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “src” «(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)»
         Match the regular expression below «(?:(?!\1).)*»
            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
            Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!\1)»
               Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
            Match any single character that is not a line break character «.»
      Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?<src>[^\s>]+)»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “src” «(?<src>[^\s>]+)»
         Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\s>]+»
            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
            A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s»
            The character “>” «>»
```

This Regex is very bad one for what you described. `src="` is a valid input.